# How to inject a script after searching on google page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to know how to inject a script when I type on google search "start extension"

I did this but didn't work

```
if(location.origin === "https://www.google.com" && location.hash.indexOf("q=start+extension")!==-1)
    (document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google don'r reload the page after a search, so you need to keep testing until you find the page you're looking for. I suggest you make a recursive call of the function with setTimeout

```
function inject()
{
    if(location.origin === "https://www.google.com" && location.hash.indexOf("q=start+extension")!==-1)
        (document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);
    else
        setTimeout(inject,2000);
}
inject();
```